# Angular carousel for 3 or more div tags

Tags: angularjs

Need to create a carousel for 3 divs containing different information, the carousel should show the current active element and should also show the beginning of the next slide,please suggest a solution to do this is the proper way. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried using angular carousel , but it slides the entire html page, i dont want that, i just want those div to change on slide

Answer (score 0):

You can try hexagon which somewhat like your expectation.

```
rn-carousel-transition : hexagon;
```

See the demo
http://blog.revolunet.com/angular-carousel/

https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel

Comment: instead of using angular carousel can we use bootstrap carousel and achieve it?